# Header misalign on change orientation when select is open in Ipad

Tags: php, ios, css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that uses bootstrap and the header uses a class navbar-fixed-top, I also have a select in this page. When I change the orientation using the ipad, it responds properly but when i open the select then change the orientation, the header width does not follow the width of the page then when the dropdown is closed it works properly again.